# How to deal with "Clang LLVM 1.0 error"?

Tags: objective-c

So I am trying to run the code that I have written up from a tutorial however I have come across this problem. Could anyone help me out?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpDZs.jpg

Comment: Are we supposed to be able to read the text in that image?  The print is too small for my eyes.

Comment: If you click on it on imgur it will show you the full size.

Answer (score 0):

first off, the error you are getting is `-fobjc-arc is not supported on platforms using the legacy runtime`. clang is exiting with a return code of 1, which just means it failed (not sure where else you are getting the "1" from).

the reason you would get that error is because you are trying to build for some old system that doesnt support ARC. you dont even specify if this is iOS or Mac OS so giving you more of an answer is difficult.

Comment: Sorry about that I'm currently using xCode 4.6.3 on OSX 10.9.3.